# f(n)=n^log(n) complexity polynomial or exponential

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I'm trying to figure out whether `f(n)=n^(logb(n))` is in `Theta(n^k)` and therefore grows polynomial or in `Theta(k^n)` and therefore grows exponentially.

First I tried to simplify the function:
`f(n) = n^(logb(n)) = n^(log(n)/log(b)) = n^((1/log(b))*log(n))` and because `1/log(b)` is constant we get `f(n)=n^log(n)`.

But now I'm stuck. My guess is that `f(n)` grows exponentially in `Theta(n^log(n))` or even hyper exponentially because the exponent `log(n)` is also growing.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining how far you got and where you are stuck

Answer (score 5):

You can write `n^(log(n))` as `(k^(logk(n)))^(log(n)) = k^(K*(log(n)^2)).` Since `(log(n))^2 < n` for n large enough, then this means that `n^(log(n))` will grow slower than k^n

Comment: Where you have used that logarithmic growth is slower than any polynomial, which includes sqrt(n).

Comment: @drizzd: Since when is sqrt(n) a polynomial?

Comment: @sleske. sqrt(n) is technically not a polynomial, but it is n^0.5, and for algorithm complexity anything O(n^k) is considered polynomial time. At least that's how I've seen it defined.

Comment: @sleske: always been: `sqrt(n) = n^(1/2)` and that is polynomial

Comment: @Simon, drizzd: Well, the common definition of a polynomial (at least in general mathematics) only allows natural numbers as exponents. But of course if you just need an upper bound, it does not make a difference to allow arbitrary real exponents, so I'm really just nitpicking :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting `n` with `b^m`, which makes `logb(n) = m`. That should get you an idea of where to go.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like it's not **theta(exponential)** or **theta(polynomial)**; the posters above showed why it is not exponential. The reason why it is not polynomial can be done with a simple proof by counter example.

proof that n^logn is not O(n^k):

- suppose there is some k, with some c and n_0 such that for n>n_0, c*n^k > n^log n. this is the definition of O(n^k).
- it is simple to find a n, with the constants, such that this doesn't hold.
- if c>1, then that n is (ck)^ck.
- if c<1, then that n is k^k.